# Find the first same number in the same index on different for loops

Tags: javascript

I want to find the first same number in the same index on different for loops and print 'Yes' if the number match and 'No' if the number does not match.

```js
const x1 = 2;
const v1 = 1;
// 2 + 1 = 3
const x2 = 1;
const v2 = 2;
// 1 + 2 = 3

// Complete the kangaroo function below.
function kangaroo(x1, v1, x2, v2) {
  let jump1 = 0;
  let jump2 = 0;

  let jumps1 = 0;
  let jumps2 = 0;

  for(let i = x1; i <= 10; i += v1) {
    jumps1 = jump1 + i;
    console.log(jumps1)
  }

  console.log('---------------------> Hold on <--------------')

  for(let i = x2; i <= 10; i += v2) {
    jumps2 = jump2 + i;
    console.log(jumps2)
  }

  if(jumps1 === jumps2) {
    console.log('Yes');
  } else {
    console.log('No');
  }

};

kangaroo(x1, v1, x2, v2);
```

Comment: do you have more background of this question to share?

Comment: The loops occur sequentially, so when do you expected them to be equal?

Comment: as you can see in the console, number 3 is in the same index position and with same number 3. When that ocurrs I want to give a string with 'Yes' and stop the sequence if not I want to give 'Not'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this better solution on the web I think is more simple. Thanks!
Here is the link if you want to check it out https://bmizepatterson.com/2018/10/01/the-kangaroo-problem/

```
function kangaroo(x1, v1, x2, v2) {

 if (v1 < v2 || (x2 - x1) % (v1 - v2) !== 0) {
  return 'NO';
 } else {
  return 'YES';
 }
};

console.log(kangaroo(x1, v1, x2, v2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add hese variables before the loops:

```
const loop1Numbers = {};
const loop2Numbers = {};
```

Add this inside your first loop:

```
loop1Numbers[i] = jumps1;
```

Add this inside your second loop:

```
loop2Numbers[i] = jumps2;
```

And finally after the loops you can check if "YES" or "NO":

```
let isThereAnyNumberEqualInSameIndex = false;
Object.keys(loop1Numbers).forEach(key => {
  if (loop1Numbers[key] === loop2Numbers[key]) isThereAnyNumberEqualInSameIndex = true
});
```

After that - isThereAnyNumberEqualInSameIndex contains `true` or `false` as you need